# How to prevent mouse motion lag in HaxeFlixel?

Tags: mouse, haxe, lag, haxeflixel

I have a boring mouse motion lag problem in HaxeFlixel. When FPS goes lower, mouse motion becomes more slower. I want to use system cursor in HaxeFlixel application. I tried these codes:

```
FlxG.mouse.setSimpleNativeCursorData("custom", BitmapData);
FlxG.mouse.registerNativeCursor("custom", MouseCursorData);
```

But my target is **CPP** and these codes don't work for my target. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need a custom cursor graphic, you can use `FlxG.mouse.useSystemCursor = true;`.

You could also try `FlxG.fixedTimestep = false;` to decrease the negative impact FPS drops have. However, this does have an effect on the accuracy of physics.

Other than that, you're pretty much out of luck - ironically, the native mouse cursor API is currently not supported on native targets by OpenFL.